# Android - how to make checking one CheckBox uncheck another?

Tags: java, android

I have two checkboxes.  If one is checked I want the other to be unchecked.

Code:

```
 CheckBox ozCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.oz);
    boolean ozInput = ozCheckBox.isChecked();
    CheckBox gCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.g);
    boolean gInput = gCheckBox.isChecked();
```

Comment: You should look into `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton` since this behavior is expected from these, but not from a `Checkbox`

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use the radio button and radio group for this purpose?
This can be done using two `RadioButton` ina `RadioGroup`. And you can style the `RadioButton` to exactly look like a `CheckBox`.

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/two">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                android:text="CheckBox One" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                android:text="CheckBox Two" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(ozCheckBox.isChecked())  //Check if first is checked
{
   //Set uncheck to second
   gInput.setChecked(false);
}
else
{
   //Set checked to second
   gInput.setChecked(true);
}
```

More accurate:

```
ozCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
if(ozCheckBox.isChecked())  //Check if first is checked
{
   //Set uncheck to second
   gInput.setChecked(false);
}
else
{
   //Set checked to second
   gInput.setChecked(true);
}
}
});
```

See here for more advice [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html)